# akka ActorIdentity.getRef() returns null in akka website example

Tags: akka, actor, akka-remote-actor

I am trying to run the example as mentioned in the tutorial [here](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-sample-remote-java?_ga=1.267043662.194745831.1436037387#code/src/main/resources/common.conf):

I downloaded the template bundle as mentioned in option 2 and configured an eclipse project with it.

When I "`Run the Lookup Example`" (from the tutorial mentioned above) in eclipse, according to the tutorial I **should** get output such as:

```
Started LookupSystem
Calculating 74 - 42
Sub result: 74 - 42 = 32
Calculating 15 + 71
Add result: 15 + 71 = 86
```

But what I **actually** get are the next lines :

```
Remote actor not available: akka.tcp://CalculatorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/calculator
Not ready yet
Not ready yet
Not ready yet
```

Repeatedly.
 The relevant lines that cause this output from *`LookupActor.java`* in function *`onReceive`* are **those**:

```
 calculator = ((ActorIdentity) message).getRef();
 if (calculator == null) {
 System.out.println("Remote actor not available: " + path);
```

(*path* is initialized to `akka.tcp://CalculatorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/calculator` in `LookupApplication` class and is passed to LookupActor.

So basically, `calculator = ((ActorIdentity) message).getRef();` **returns null always**, and that is what causes this output.

What I have tried to do so far:

I tried to change the *path* variable in class *`LookupApplication`* from:

```
 akka.tcp://CalculatorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/calculator
```

to

```
 akka.tcp://CalculatorSystem@127.0.0.1:2552/user/CalculatorActor
```

and the line:

```
 system.actorOf(Props.create(CalculatorActor.class),calculator);
```

to:

```
 system.actorOf(Props.create(CalculatorActor.class), CalculatorActor.class.getSimpleName());
```

as I understood from what is mentioned [here](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/akka-user/13bjj3h9k0/akka-remote-newbie-question).

But it did not help, it returns null always.  I assume this is a problem, since the tutorial says that the output should be different.

Would appreciate any help

---

EDIT:
I edited "`onRecieve`" method in `LookupActor` class like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
     // if (message instanceof ActorIdentity) {
     // calculator = ((ActorIdentity) message).getRef();
    if (message == null) {
       System.out.println("Remote actor not available: " + path);

    } else {
         getContext().watch(calculator);
         getContext().become(active, true);
      }

//      } else if (message instanceof ReceiveTimeout) {
//          sendIdentifyRequest();
//
//        } else {
//             System.out.println("Not ready yet");
//
//          }
}
```

and created an enum:

```
private enum msg{
  GREET;
}
```

and updated method "`sendIdentifyRequest`", instead of :

```
getContext().actorSelection(path).tell(new Identify(path), getSelf());
```

It is now

```
getContext().actorSelection(path).tell(msg.GREET, getSelf());
```

It is working now, But I don't think this is the proper solution, it's just a workaround that avoids the real problem.

---

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tutorial code, but I'm unsure about what your question actually is. can you elaborate a proper question you'd like answered?

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia I emphasized the concrete parts with **bold**, hopefully it's explaining the problem a little better. The problem is the difference in the output between my program and what is written in the tutorial. What is causing this is that in method `onRecieve`, the line`calculator = ((ActorIdentity) message).getRef();` returns null; Thank you

Comment: If you look at the code, the line "Not ready yet" is printed when the message type received from the LookupActor is neither Timeout or ActorIdentity . Clearly something is going wrong: I reccomend you modify the branch where it prints "Not ready yet" with something that prints out the message type received and its content, to help you debugging. I don't think this has nothing to do with the name of the actor (which is what you have changed from "calculator" to "CalculatorActor"

Answer (score 0):

It is because of path issue, the ConfigFactory couldn't load configs such as: remotelookup.conf, calculator.conf, and so on. As the config loading failed, ConfigFactory returned to use the default Config which is akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider instead of akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.

this line won't work:

```
public static void startRemoteWorkerSystem() {
  ActorSystem.create("CalculatorWorkerSystem",
  ConfigFactory.load(("calculator"))); 
  System.out.println("Started CalculatorWorkerSystem");
}
```

> ConfigFactory.load(("calculator")));

Move those configs file in src/main/resources to the path where accessible by akka.

If you are using Netbean / other IDE and don't configure the path correctly, place it under target/classes/ or target/ or bin/ or where they put their compiled class.